# Asp.Net Toggle checked property of a Data Bound checkbox

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a GridView control that has one column of checkboxes set up like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="RowCheckBox" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%# (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem ,"Associated") %>'/>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then when the user clicks an Edit button I run a script that enables all the checkboxes (which works fine), and then when the user then clicks on a checkbox the tick is appearing or disappearing as it should.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to read the value of the checkbox from the codebehind:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) row.FindControl("RowCheckBox");
bool checked = checkBox.Checked;
```

If the value bound to it was `true` then `checked` is still `true`, no matter if it was toggled or not.

Has anyone got any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I couldn't find a solution so have done a work around:

1. Add a Hidden Field to the Template Field,
2. Update the value of the hidden field to `True` or `False` with Javascript (adding an `onclick` attribute to the checkbox),
3. In the code behind cast the hidden field `value` to a bool and use that instead of the checked property of the checkbox.

I think it might be something to do with View States, but I'm not sure what they are and haven't got the time to investigate unfortunately.

Clivest